# how to exclude the dirty data which would lead to SQLException by hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate

Please find the following mapping xml,

```
<class name="com.fabulous.A" table="f_a">
    <id name="id" column="id">
        <generator class="assigned" />
    </id>
    <property name="startTime" column="start_time" />
</class>
```

I query table f_a by batch as below, the batch size is 100:

```
"FROM A WHERE id IN (:ids)"
```

However **there is a dirty row in table f_a which would lead to SQLException**, and the whole batch will be failed to get.

I have only select privilege and can't delete the dirty data from DB, **is there any way from hibernate to exclude the dirty data** automatically by hibernate?

Yes, if query by id one by one I can make it from my application but it's inefficient and unavailable.

Could anyone help with this? 
The dirty data is timestamp valued "0000:00:00".

Thanks.

Comment: why not add another condition: `WHERE id IN (:ids) and startTime != '0000:00:00'` ?

Comment: @JorgeCampos Yes, it works, but not looks good. If there is another better method I'll take it. Thanks man.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it with appending `?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull` on the jdbcUrl.

You may find my jdbcUrl as below

```
<property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testdb?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an option `<property name="hibernate.connection.zeroDateTimeBehavior">convertToNull</property`>

to your `hibernate.cfg.xml:`

Or in `hibernate.properties`:

```
hibernate.connection.zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull
```

Comment: Add it to my configuration , not sure why it doesn't work.